# freeglut Keyboard Issues

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

The issue is when I press 'shift' other keys on the keyboard stick. here is the code i am using (credit for original code goes to Nghia Ho)

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "Camera.h"

using namespace std;

void Display();
void Reshape (int w, int h);
void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void KeyboardUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void MouseMotion(int x, int y);
void Mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void Timer(int value);
void Idle();

void Grid();

Camera g_camera;
bool g_key[256];
bool g_shift_down = false;
bool g_fps_mode = false;
int g_viewport_width = 0;
int g_viewport_height = 0;
bool g_mouse_left_down = false;
bool g_mouse_right_down = false;

// Movement settings
const float g_translation_speed = 0.05;
const float g_rotation_speed = M_PI/180*0.2;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("FPS demo by Nghia Ho - Hit SPACEBAR to toggle FPS mode");

    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutIdleFunc(Display);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(MouseMotion);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(MouseMotion);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(KeyboardUp);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);

    glutTimerFunc(1, Timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void Grid()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1,1,1);

    for(int i=-50; i < 50; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(i, 0, -50);
        glVertex3f(i, 0, 50);
        glEnd();
    }

    for(int i=-50; i < 50; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(-50, 0, i);
        glVertex3f(50, 0, i);
        glEnd();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
}

void Display (void) {
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //clear the screen to black
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //clear the color buffer and the depth buffer
    glLoadIdentity();

    g_camera.Refresh();

    glColor3f(0,1,0);

    glutWireTeapot(0.5);
    Grid();

    glutSwapBuffers(); //swap the buffers
}

void Reshape (int w, int h) {
    g_viewport_width = w;
    g_viewport_height = h;

    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h); //set the viewport to the current window specifications
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION); //set the matrix to projection

    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.1 , 100.0); //set the perspective (angle of sight, width, height, ,depth)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW); //set the matrix back to model
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == 27) {
        exit(0);
    }

    if(key == ' ') {
        g_fps_mode = !g_fps_mode;

        if(g_fps_mode) {
            glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
            glutWarpPointer(g_viewport_width/2, g_viewport_height/2);
        }
        else {
            glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_LEFT_ARROW);
        }
    }

    if(glutGetModifiers() == GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT) {
        g_shift_down = true;
    }
    else {
        g_shift_down = false;
    }

    g_key[key] = true;
}

void KeyboardUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    g_key[key] = false;
}

void Timer(int value)
{
    if(g_fps_mode) {
        if(g_key['w'] || g_key['W']) {
            g_camera.Move(g_translation_speed);
        }
        else if(g_key['s'] || g_key['S']) {
            g_camera.Move(-g_translation_speed);
        }
        else if(g_key['a'] || g_key['A']) {
            g_camera.Strafe(g_translation_speed);
        }
        else if(g_key['d'] || g_key['D']) {
            g_camera.Strafe(-g_translation_speed);
        }
        else if(g_mouse_left_down) {
            g_camera.Fly(-g_translation_speed);
        }
        else if(g_mouse_right_down) {
            g_camera.Fly(g_translation_speed);
        }
    }

    glutTimerFunc(1, Timer, 0);
}

void Idle()
{
    Display();
}

void Mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
            g_mouse_left_down = true;
        }
        else if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
            g_mouse_right_down = true;
        }
    }
    else if(state == GLUT_UP) {
        if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
            g_mouse_left_down = false;
        }
        else if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
            g_mouse_right_down = false;
        }
    }
}

void MouseMotion(int x, int y)
{
    // This variable is hack to stop glutWarpPointer from triggering an event callback to Mouse(...)
    // This avoids it being called recursively and hanging up the event loop
    static bool just_warped = false;

    if(just_warped) {
        just_warped = false;
        return;
    }

    if(g_fps_mode) {
        int dx = x - g_viewport_width/2;
        int dy = y - g_viewport_height/2;

        if(dx) {
            g_camera.RotateYaw(g_rotation_speed*dx);
        }

        if(dy) {
            g_camera.RotatePitch(g_rotation_speed*dy);
        }

        glutWarpPointer(g_viewport_width/2, g_viewport_height/2);

        just_warped = true;
    }
}
```

the strange thing is is when i press any other key it fixes it the first time but it doesn't fix it the second time
Thanks a ton!

Comment: Generally for stack overflow it's a good idea to make a bare bones (super basic) example and see if the problem is still present. It also makes it easier to follow.

Comment: ill keep note of that thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that GLUT keyboard func does not give you key codes, i.e. the numeric representation of which key and modifiers have been pressed, but character codes, i.e. which letter form is produced by that. Of course an upper case character has a different character code than its lower case counterpart. And holding shift will of course alter upper/lower case.

Actually GLUT is not particularly well suited for the kind of input you want. It's far simpler to do this with GLFW or SDL. However in your particular case there's an easy solution: Just convert all incoming character codes to lower case before indexing in the "key pressed" array:

```
#include <ctype.h> /* for tolower */

/* ... */

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    key = tolower(key); /* <--- */

    if(key == 27) {
        exit(0);
    }

    if(key == ' ') {
        g_fps_mode = !g_fps_mode;

        if(g_fps_mode) {
            glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
            glutWarpPointer(g_viewport_width/2, g_viewport_height/2);
        }
        else {
            glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_LEFT_ARROW);
        }
    }

    if(glutGetModifiers() == GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT) {
        g_shift_down = true;
    }
    else {
        g_shift_down = false;
    }

    g_key[key] = true;
}
```